# How to add arabic characters in a middle of a file using C++?

Tags: c++, unicode, ascii, wofstream

I am building an application that will need to add arabic characters in the middle of english file, I build the function as follow:

```
int main(void) {

    std::ifstream mySource("Test2.txt", std::ios::out);
    std::filebuf* pbuf = mySource.rdbuf();
    std::size_t size = pbuf->pubseekoff(0, mySource.end, mySource.in);
    pbuf->pubseekpos(0, mySource.in);
    char* buffer = new  char[size];
    pbuf->sgetn(buffer, size);
    mySource.close();

    wchar_t* wbuffer = new wchar_t[size];
    wbuffer = GetWC(buffer);

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_GB.utf8");
    wbuffer[79] = {0x0041};
   
    std::wofstream outdata2;
    outdata2.open("Test6.xml"); // opens the file
    outdata2 << wbuffer;
    outdata2.close();
  
    return 0;
}
```

for a text file as follows:

```
$ cat dat/rbgtst.txt
400,280: (234,163,097) #EAA361
400,300: (000,000,000) #000000
400,320: (064,101,160) #4065A0
400,340: (220,194,110) #DCC26E
```

and expecting to receive

```
$ cat dat/rbgtst.txt
400,280: (234,163,097) #EAA361
400,300: (000,000,000) #A00000
400,320: (064,101,160) #4065A0
400,340: (220,194,110) #DCC26E
```

although when I put the arabic letter ASCII like:

```
...
wbuffer[79] = {0x0628};
...
```

I receive the following:

```
$ cat dat/rbgtst.txt
400,280: (234,163,097) #EAA361
400,300: (000,000,000) #
```

don't know why?!

Comment: Does your terminal can draw arabic characters?

Comment: I can not see where you `add` the letter, only that you replace, is that what you meant?

Comment: No, my terminal can't see arabic, but i see the changes in the output file. All what I need to do is to replace character in the file with arabic character.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are using for output will terminate at a null character. Instead you should use `ostream::write` for the output

```
outdata2.write(wbuffer, size);
```

Also since you are doing binary I/O all your files should be opened with the `std::ios::binary` bit set.

```
std::ifstream mySource("Test2.txt", std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the changes as follows and gives same result.

Comment: @MohsenDeeb I don't think I understand your problem. There are no Arabic characters in the file, only numbers and punctuation.